# Hibernate JPA Query multiple join tables

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

i can't understand one thing.

Here is test DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE public.role
(
    id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE public.role_translate
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  roleId INT REFERENCES public.role(id),
  locale VARCHAR(2)
);

CREATE TABLE public.users
(
    uuid UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
    uuid UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
  , username VARCHAR(45) UNIQUE
  , email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE public.user_role
(
    uuid     UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
  , userUuid UUID REFERENCES public.users(uuid) NOT NULL
  , roleId INT REFERENCES public.role(id) NOT NULL
);
```

Okay. Now i show you POJO classes.

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "catalog", schema = "public")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1325687088267757690L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    //....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

UserRole class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", catalog = "catalog", schema = "public")
public class UserRole {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1935684358277757690L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid", strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
    private UUID uuid;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Role role;
}
```

Role class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role", catalog = "catalog", schema = "public")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2874365798237423123L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "roles_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "roles_seq_gen", sequenceName = "roles_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<RoleTranslate> roleTranslateList;

    //...
}
```

So, user can has many roles.

Now i want to get this - i want to find user by username field and role, but i have to find role by locale.

This SQL do what i want:

```
SELECT * FROM user_role UR 
  JOIN role R ON R.id = UR.roleid 
  JOIN role_translate RT ON RT.roleid = R.id 
  JOIN USERS U ON U.uuid = UR.useruuid 
WHERE U.username = 'username' AND RT.LOCALE = 'de';
```

Here is what i tried:

```
    EntityManager em = sessionFactory.createEntityManager();
    em.createQuery("select r from User u " +
            "join fetch u.userRoles ur " +
            "join fetch ur.role r " +
            "join fetch r.roleTranslateList rt " +
            "where u.username = :username AND rt.locale = 'de'", User.class)
            .setParameter("username", username)
            .getSingleResult();
    em.createQuery(
            "select u " +
                    "from User u " +
                    "inner join fetch u.userRoles ur " +
                    "inner join fetch ur.role r " +
                    "inner join fetch r.roleTranslateList rt " +
                    "where u.username = :username AND rt.locale = 'de'", User.class)
            .setParameter("username", username)
            .getResultList();
```

But i can't understand how i can implement this using JPA mechanism. All my variants gives me NPE or something else. I want implement method which return me `User` class with `Collection<UserRole> userRoles` where would exist list of `UserRole` class objects, where class `Role` would have only translate for `de` locale translate.

Comment: That's not how JPA associations work. The collection of RoleTranslate in Role is the whole set of RoleTranslate of that Role. Always. It doesn't depend on the context, or on which query you executed before to load the role. If you want a precise collection of RoleTranslate, then use a query that selects RoleTranslate. Like for example `select rt from User u join u.userRoles ur join ur.role r join r.roleTranslateList rt where ...`.

Comment: In this case what POJO i will retrieve?

Comment: The query is `select rt`, so you will get a List<RoleTranslate>. But you can also use `select u, rt ...`. And you'll then get a List<Object[]>, where the first element will be a User, and the second, one of its RoleTranslate.

Comment: But what if i need to select 10000 users and for every user i have to have actual List<RoleTranslate> with specific locale. How i can implement this?

Comment: Create a Map<User, List<RoleTranslate>>, loop through the list, and for each row, get the list associated to the user from the map, create it if it isn't there yet, and add the RoleTranslate to the list. Could be done in 3 lines of code with a Stream.

Comment: Yeah, 3 lines. But what about time? If I need get 1M rows...  Why this case solution so terrible?! Okay, write your solution as answer - I accept it.

Comment: Why would you need to get 1M rows. If you have 10000 users, and each users has 2 RoleTranslate with the locale you're looking for, you'll get 20000 rows, just like you would get with a SQL query.

Comment: Okay, Users it is just a test case. Questions. Billions questions. All questions have 4-5 localizations. And we have user answers to questions. And again I want to get UserAnswer class which contains Question class which contains QuestionTranslate class with localized string. And again I can't get them in one SQL. Same situation.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here. Of course, loading billions of rows in memory will not work. That has nothing to do with your original question. And of course, you should not do that.

Comment: I can update my answer with other database ddl, where translate class not for user class, but for Question class. And I have to get 1M rows but I want to filter my rows in database and get full ready POJO classes, not creating streams or loop cycles to set List of Translate to POJO. Write your solution as answer to this question.